# (Java ) problems with myString.charAt(i) > "1" or myString.charAt(i) < "A"

Tags: java, string

I have a car Object which is supposed to have a characteristic. The characteristic is supposed to have the requirements: starts with two capital letter followed by a number from 1-9 followed by 4 numbers from 0-9.

```
 public void writeCharacteristic(){
```

`System.out.println("write down the characteristic for the car.");
    String characteristic = kb.nextLine();

    progress = false; 

    if (characteristic.length() != 7){
        System.out.println("The string is not 7 letter/numbers long");
        progress = false; 
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
         if (characteristic.charAt(i) < "A" || characteristic.charAt(i) > "Z"){
        System.out.println(" character number " + i + " is invalid");
        progress = false;
         }

    }

    if (characteristic.charAt(3) < "1" || characteristic.charAt(3) > "9")
        progress = false;

    for (int j = 3; j < 7; ++j){
        if (characteristic.charAt(j) < 0 || characteristic.charAt(j) > 9)
            progress =false;
    }
        if (progress == false){
            System.out.println("characteristic will have the value null.");
            characteristic = null;
        }

        if (progress == true)
                car.setCharacteristic(characteristic);`

}

I'm having a problem at the lines "if (characteristic.charAt(i) < "A" || characteristic.charAt(i) > "Z"){"

The compiler is saying "The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) char, String"

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, you can compare a character (`char`) to a character, but you can't compare a character to a `String`. `charAt` returns a character, so you must compare its result to a character.

These are `String`

```
"A" "Z" "1" "9"
```

And these are characters

```
'A' 'Z' '1' '9'
```

---

You can compare a character to an integer (`int`), but the result may not be what you want. So in the code below:

```
for (int j = 3; j < 7; ++j){
    if (characteristic.charAt(j) < 0 || characteristic.charAt(j) > 9)
```

`0` and `9` should be change to `'0'` and `'9'`.

---

Note: There is another unrelated logic error in your code:

```
String characteristic = kb.nextLine();

progress = false;
```

Shouldn't `progress` be set to `true` here?

Comment: And these are letters and numbers `A Z 1 9`

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly check out the other answers on this page re. character comparisons. However, I would perhaps suggest a different approach given:

> starts with two capital letter followed by a number from 1-9 followed
>   by 4 numbers from 0-9

and investigate [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Something like:

```
[A-Z]{2}[1-9][0-9]{4}
```

would satisfy the above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

**Use single quotes for chars, double quotes for Strings.**

```
 characteristic.charAt(3) < '1'
```

there is meaning for single and double quotes in java

And for  your situation best suits is  a regex

Answer (score 0):

Replace the double quotes with single quotes.

You'll also have to put single quotes around the numbers when comparing them with chars, even though the compiler doesn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

Compare like this

```
characteristic.charAt(3) < '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can achieve this goal with regexp: 
`[A-Z]{2}[1-9][0-9]{4}` 
(Read [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) article to know how to use it).

If you want to do it as you started - use singleqoutes instead of doublequotes with characters. e.g. `"a"` -> `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign value to `char` use single quote. If it is a `String` use double quote

```
 char myChar='a';

 String myString="a";
```

so

```
 characteristic.charAt(3) < "1"  should change as characteristic.charAt(3) < '1'
```